# how to remove the ( ) and , in a floating point

Tags: python, floating-point, gps, latitude-longitude

```
latitude = bytes([data[12],data[11],data[10],data[9]])
        longitude = bytes([data[16],data[15],data[14],data[13]])

        intLat = struct.unpack('!f',latitude)
        intLong = struct.unpack('!f',longitude)

        print(intLat) 
        print(intLong)
```

this is the coding printed.

```
(100.47630310058594,)
(5.136366844177246,)
```

how to remove the ( ) and , ?
because i just want the floating to store in database, with out () and ,

Comment: `intLat = struct.unpack('!f',latitude)[0]` will do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the first element of the tuple:

```
intLat = struct.unpack('!f',latitude)[0]
intLong = struct.unpack('!f',longitude)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(100.47630310058594,)
```

This means the data is a `tuple` with just one element. You can get the data by indexing like you do for a list.

```
intLong[0]
```

will get you the data.

Or you can just index the output of unpack as Volatility mentioned.